# Сделать аутентификацию на сайт

Tags: php

День добрый! Подскажите где почитать об авторизации на сайт через гугл. CMS самописная.

Comment: Пожалуй начать стоит с документации гугла https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in

Comment: Я делал через сервис https://ulogin.ru/ очень удобно и много сос сетей в добавок